# React: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setExtraStackFrame') in local

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, create-react-app, webpack-module-federation

I am using react-app-rewired to configure ModuleFederation to make my CRA app Microfrontend compatible. I am using react-scripts 5 and my webpack config looks like this

```
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin = require('external-remotes-plugin');
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

module.exports = {
    webpack(config, env) {
        config.output.publicPath = 'auto';
        config.resolve.fallback = {
            net: false,
        };
        config.resolve.alias = {
            'react/jsx-dev-runtime': 'react/jsx-dev-runtime.js',
            'react/jsx-runtime': 'react/jsx-runtime.js',
        };
        config.plugins.push(
            new NodePolyfillPlugin({
                excludeAliases: ['console'],
            })
        );
        config.plugins.push(
            new ModuleFederationPlugin({
                name: 'MyApp',
                filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
                remotes: {},
                shared: {
                    ...deps,
                    react: {
                        singleton: true,
                        requiredVersion: deps.react,
                    },
                    'react-dom': {
                        singleton: true,
                        requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
                    },
                },
            }),
            new ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin()
        );
        return config;
    },
};
```

The package.json scripts is as follows

```
 "start": "node --max-http-header-size=16384 index",
 "start:dev:react": "react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=4096 start",
 "start:dev": "concurrently -k \"npm run start\" \"npm run start:dev:react\"",
 "build": "react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
 "coverage": "CI=true react-app-rewired test --ci --coverage",
 "test": "npm run coverage",
 "eject": "react-app-rewired eject",
```

The app runs fine when production build is created (i.e) after npm run build. But does not work locally and fails with the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setExtraStackFrame')
    at setCurrentlyValidatingElement$1 (react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:872:1)
    at validateExplicitKey (react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:984:1)
    at validateChildKeys (react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:1013:1)
    at jsxWithValidation (react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:1184:1)
    at MyComponent (MyComponent.js:99:1)
    at oo (react-dom.production.min.js:157:137)
    at Ku (react-dom.production.min.js:267:460)
    at zi (react-dom.production.min.js:250:347)
    at Ni (react-dom.production.min.js:250:278)
    at Pi (react-dom.production.min.js:250:138)
    at bi (react-dom.production.min.js:243:163)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123:115
    at n.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18:343)
    at $l (react-dom.production.min.js:122:325)
    at Yl (react-dom.production.min.js:123:61)
    at Kl (react-dom.production.min.js:122:428)
```

All other links on the internet leads me to this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20359
But I am really not able to come to a solution to fix this.

EDIT: When I load remote modules from localhost/remoteEntry.js the app runs without error. It fails when I load remoteEntry from a production app.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I have the same issue, using WMF, and am locally getting this error while in the production build everything works okay. I checked if I'm missing `key` prop somewhere, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score -1):

I followed this instruction: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20359#issuecomment-1177480160

Of adding a `key` property, and that has fixed my issue!